# Instant search using optional Logical Operators to filter results

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search

I'm trying to write a search function that can use logical operator to filter results. The way the code works is that I can type out a string to search or I can put < or an > at the beginning of the text field to filter for greater or less numerical values. I'm looking for a better version or way to write it. I have a (semi) working version, but the way I wrote it I have to put one or two zeros if the value isn't more than three digits. For example, <050 has to be used to search for items under 50. Using <50 by itself brings up wrong results. In addition, if the result is under 100 I'm having to convert the value from say 5 to 005. This works only if the largest value is under 1k otherwise I have to convert to 0005.

```
function FullListSearch() { 
  $("#InfoSearch").keyup(function() {
    var V = this.value;
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    Operator = value[0];
    len = $(this).val().length;

    if ( Operator == ">" ) { 
      $("#Info").find(".fulllist").each(function() {
         var ths = $(this).text();
         var Npattern = /[0-9]+/g;
         var Nmatches = ths.match(Npattern);
         var ValN = V.match(Npattern);
     if (Nmatches.length > "1") {
       if (Nmatches[1].length == "1") { Nmatches[1] = "00" + Nmatches[1] };
          $(this).show();
       if (Nmatches[1] < ValN) {
              $(this).toggle();
       }
     }
     else { alert("the > operator is not valid with this object");
             return false;
          }
    });
  }

  else if ( Operator == "<" ) { 
    $("#Info").find(".fulllist").each(function() {
     var ths = $(this).text();
     var Npattern = /[0-9]+/g;
     var Nmatches = ths.match(Npattern);
     var ValN = V.match(Npattern);
      if (Nmatches.length > "1") {
        if (Nmatches[1].length == "1") { Nmatches[1] = "00" + Nmatches[1] };
        $(this).show();
        if (Nmatches[1] > ValN) {
            $(this).toggle();
      }
     }
     else { alert("the > operator is not valid with this object");
             return false;
     }
    });
  }

  else { 
    $("#Info").find(".fulllist").each(function() {
      var id = $(this).first().text().toLowerCase()
          $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
    });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I know the formatting looks wacky. I'm at work and copy/paste wasn't very friendly. I'll clean it up here in a bit.

Comment: can you post your code and related html on jsfiddle so that we have a working script to play with?

Comment: I'll try to hash something out tonight. A lot of the code is dynamically created from an array that is dynamically created from a json file which gets it's information from a ps script. (Yes I can use VBscript in my HTA but it slows performance when it queries the server.)

Comment: Here it is in basic form: http://jsfiddle.net/aNDpd/1/

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like:

```
function FullListSearch() {
    $("#InfoSearch").keyup(function () {
        var V = this.value;
        var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
        var Operator = value[0];

        var compFunc = function (a, b) {
            return a == b;
        };

        if (Operator == '>' || Operator == '<') {
            value = value.substring(1);

            if (Operator == '>') compFunc = function (a, b) {
                return a > b;
            };
            else // '<' 
            compFunc = function (a, b) {
                return a < b;
            };
        }
        var numVal = parseInt(value);
        if (isNaN(numVal)) alert("invalid input!");

        $("#Info").find(".fulllist").each(function () {
            var val = parseInt($(this).text());
            $(this)[compFunc(val, numVal) ? "show" : "hide"]();
        });
    });
}
```

I haven't checked this, but the idea should be clear.

Few notes:

1. Regular expressions are not always the best way to validate, and if so, use something more general such as `/^[><]?\d+$/` to validate the entire thing.
2. Why are comparing each digit, when you can compare numbers? Use `parseInt()`.
3. I wouldn't fire this whole code on every keyup, but wait some time in order to see if a new key is pressed. Something like:

   ```
    $("#InfoSearch").keyup(function () {
         var timeout = $(this).data("timeout");
         if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
         $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout(function () {...........}, 200); // milliseconds
    }
   ```

Comment: ParseInt only works if the string starts with a number which mine does not. Each string says something like 'Server 1 Uptime: 125 hours'. I can use a timeout, but I'm not sure what the performance increase would be. It's pretty responsive as it is. I'll give it a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Why don't you store the compared time outside the text inside an attribute, like: `<div class="fulllist" time="125"> Server 1 Uptime: 125 hours </div>`.

Comment: Do you mean that only the second parsing wouldn't be executable?

Comment: I'll try storing the compared time outside the text inside the attribute. That's a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution. Thanks to EZSlaver for suggesting that I store my int inside an attribute and for suggesting that I not use regex to validate.

```
function FullListSearch() {
  $("#InfoSearch").keyup(function() {
  var V = parseInt(this.value);
      var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
  Operator = $('select option:selected').val();

   $("#Info").find(".fulllist").each(function() {
     $(this).show();
     var NumVal = $(this).attr('time');
     if ( (Operator == 'greater') && (NumVal < V)) {
      $(this).hide();
     }
     if ( (Operator == 'lesser') && (NumVal > V)) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
     if (Operator == "equal") {
       var id = $(this).first().text().toLowerCase()
       $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
     }
   });
  });   
}
```